# How to make several plots on the same page in R using cowplot package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I am using built-in data set iris in R, I want to plot several graphs on the same page for which I am using cowplot package. 
However, the problem I face is that the labels in the figures i,e "A" and "B" overlap the y-axix. How can I lleave some space in between labels and y-axis? 
My code is:

```
View(iris)
library(tidyverse)

p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, col = Species))+geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width, col = Species))+geom_point()
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(p1,p2, labels = c("(A)","(B)"))
```

[image]

Comment: Is using `ggplot2`'s `facet_wrap` of `face_grid` an option?

Comment: I want the figures exactly as above in the question with that minor correction. So if facet_wrap can do that, you are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to work with the options of `plot_grid`, the default are these:

```
plot_grid(p1,p2, labels = c("(A)","(B)"), align = 'h', label_size = 12,
          label_x = 0, label_y = 1, hjust = -0.5, vjust = 1.5 )
```

For example, something like this:

```
plot_grid(p1,p2, labels = c("(A)","(B)"), align = 'h', label_size = 12,
          label_x = 0, label_y = 1, hjust = -0.1, vjust = 5 )
```